# How to serialize a collection into WCF from WebRequest

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, webrequest

We have a partner company that is posting us XML via the webRequest (C#) function.

The XML structure is fixed, I can't change the way the XML looks.

The following is an example of what happens and what code I'm doing. The XML is an example of what the XML looks like in Fiddler.

```
<Sales>
   <Customer>
        <Name>John</Name>
   </Customer>
   <Goods>
      <Good>
         <id>5445</id>
      </Good>
      <Good>
         <id>6767</id>
      </Good>
   </Goods>
</Sales>
```

My WCF function is

```
public Sales(clsCustomer Customer, clsGoods Good);
```

My interface is

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "SendRequest", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
public Sales(clsCustomer Customer, clsGoods Goods)
```

My classes are

```
[DataContract(NameSpace="http://example.com/Int")]
public class Customer {
    [DataMember(Name="Name",Order=1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(NameSpace="http://example.com/Int")]
public class clsGoods {
    public List<clsGood> Good { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(NameSpace="http://example.com/Int")]
public class clsGood {
    public string id {get; set;}
}
```

When I use `WebRequest` to post my service, the Customer field get filled but `Goods` collection is always blank.

Answer (score 0):

you need to decorate (public List Good { get; set; }) as your data member

like this:

```
[DataMember]
public List<clsGood> Good { get; set; }
```

Comment: I did try that but it didn't work.  When I have it as a singular node, .i.e.

    [DataMember]
    public clsGood Good { get; set; }

I can get a clsGood item but it can't handle multiple goods.

Comment: Something that I have discovered is although the XML is as above as seen in Fiddler, when it arrives at the Webservice and processed, Namespaces appear where they weren't before. <Good xlmns="example.com/Int">; Even when I remove the namespaces, they still appear.